# Type Mismatch error returning mailitem property from an item

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have this code below.

I get

> runtime error 13 type mismatch

at `objMail.ReceivedTime`.

I tried `On Error Resume Next`.

```vb
Sub ExportAttachmentsLastWeek()
    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim strFolderPath As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim dtmCriteria As Date

    Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNS = objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = objNS.PickFolder

    If objFolder Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    strFolderPath = "C:\Users\evansj01\Documents\"
  
   'Calculate date 1 week ago
    dtmCriteria = Now() - 7
    
    For Each objMail In objFolder.Items
        'Check if the email received date is within the last week
        If objMail.ReceivedTime >= dtmCriteria Then
            If objMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
                For Each objAttachment In objMail.Attachments
                    If Right(objAttachment.FileName, 3) = "xls" Then 'change file format as needed
                        strFileName = strFolderPath & objMail.Subject & "_" & objAttachment.FileName
                        objAttachment.SaveAsFile strFileName
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    Set objAttachment = Nothing
    Set objMail = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
    Set objOL = Nothing
End Sub
```

I was hoping it would download all Excel files received in that time period to the folder selected.

Comment: Do you get the error on the `For Each objMail In objFolder.Items` line (ie if you press 'Debug' in the error dialog)?

Comment: On which code line is the mentioned error raised?

Comment: Hi John, when I hit the debug It wasn't highlighting a line like it normally does in yellow. I stepped through it and it seems to stop at objMail.ReceivedTime so it could probably be the For Each objMail In objFolder.Items section causing the issue as that's the line before it?

Comment: You have objMail.Subject as part of the file name so it must not contain any of the following characters `/ \ : * ? " < > |`

Comment: "I've tried on error resume next no luck." This dangerous code is seldom useful and often fatal.  https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (two changes from your code, both commented):

```
Sub ExportAttachmentsLastWeek()
    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim objMail As Object ' changed from Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim strFolderPath As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim dtmCriteria As Date

    Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNS = objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = objNS.PickFolder

    If objFolder Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    strFolderPath = "C:\Users\evansj01\Documents\"
  
   'Calculate date 1 week ago
    dtmCriteria = Now() - 7
    
    For Each objMail In objFolder.Items
        ' additional test for type of item
        If TypeOf objMail Is MailItem Then
            'Check if the email received date is within the last week
            If objMail.ReceivedTime >= dtmCriteria Then
                If objMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
                    For Each objAttachment In objMail.Attachments
                        If Right(objAttachment.FileName, 3) = "xls" Then 'change file format as needed
                            strFileName = strFolderPath & objMail.Subject & "_" & objAttachment.FileName
                            objAttachment.SaveAsFile strFileName
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    Set objAttachment = Nothing
    Set objMail = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
    Set objOL = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi John, Thank you so much for your reply. That has fixed the Runtime error. I now get a "Cannot save the attachment" error. (Also I tried to upvote your code as a thank you but it wont let me as I don't have a level 15 reputation.)

Comment: No worries ... please ask a separate question for the new problem ... I (or someone else) will assist ...